# What is this function's behavior?

Tags: asymptotics, special-functions

What is behavior of this $f(a)=(\sqrt a)^{f(\sqrt a)}$ at a given $a\in\Bbb R$?

Does it converge to some explicit value at $a=2$ and if so what is it?

Comment: Did you mean to specify a function, or only give a functional equation?

Comment: For $a=2$, it looks like it converges to around 1.52040060870843169, but I have no idea of how you'd find that analytically, or even how to prove convergence, I just wrote a simple recursive function in Python.

Comment: @PM2Ring How does it converge without basis conditions?

Comment: @TiwaAina I use $f(1) = 1$ as the base of the recursion. To limit the recursion depth I return 1 if $x$ is very close to 1.

Answer (score 3):

I'm also unsure about an analytic solution—however, there are some interesting observations we can make:

1. If we write the functional relationship another way,$$f(b^2) = b^{f(b)}$$

   we can see that if $f(b)= 2$, then $b^2$ is a fixed point of $f$, since then $f(b^2) = b^{f(b)} = b^2.$ (The case $b=1$ is special, but the conclusion still holds).
2. Also for a fixed point $b^2$, we have that $f(f(b)) = f(2)$.
3. We know that $f(1) = 1$. Hence because repeated applications of the square root function converge to 1, we can write:

   $$f(x) \approx \begin{cases}1 & \text{if }x \approx 1\\ \sqrt{x}^{f(\sqrt{x})}&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
   and the result will converge.
4. With such approximations, we find that:

   - $f(2) \approx 1.52040060871$
   - $f$ is strictly increasing; there's exactly one point $b$ for which $f(b)=2$. It occurs at $b \approx 2.80449202$
   - This point $b$ is significant because it implies that $b^2$ is a fixed point of $f$. Indeed, $b^2 = f(b^2) \approx 7.8651755$
5. Finally, we can plot the function; it looks like this:

   [image]
6. There's a family of similar relations which define other functions:
   $$f(a) = a^{k\cdot f(a^k)}$$
   The function described here represents the case $k=\frac{1}{2}$.

   When $k=1$, we can actually find a closed form for the solution. The functional relation becomes simply $f(a) = a^{f(a)}$, so 
   $$\log(f(a)) = \log(a) \cdot f(a) $$
   $$\frac{\log(f(a))}{f(a)} = \log(a)$$
   $$f(a) = \frac{W[-\log(a)]}{-\log(a)}$$

   where $W$ is the Lambert $W$ function (which may be useful for solving this problem more generally.)

Answer (score 1):

It seems we have to take $a>0$ anyway.

For $a<0$ it is undefined and $f(0)=0^{f(0)}$ is also full of contradictions.

$f(1)=1^{f(1)}=1$

So assuming $f$ is continuous and since $\sqrt[n]{a}\to 1$ we can expect $\Large f(a)=\sqrt{a}^{\sqrt[4]{a}^{\sqrt[8]{a}^{\cdots}}}$

However I don't know if we can rewrite this tetration in a simpler way.